# Mocking asynchronous service function using angular/karma/jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, mocking, karma-jasmine

The test in this code does not succeed.  I can't seem to successfully test the return of an asynchronous function.

```
describe('mocking services', function () {

    var someService, deferred;

    beforeEach(function () {

        module(function($provide){
            $provide.factory('someService', function($q){
                return{
                    trySynch: function(){
                        return 33;
                    },
                    tryAsynch: function(){
                        deferred = $q.defer();
                        return deferred.promise;
                    }
                };
            });
        });

        inject(function (_someService_) {
            someService = _someService_;
        });
    });

    it('should be able to test values from both functions', function () {
        expect(someService.trySynch()).toEqual(33);

        var retVal;
        someService.tryAsynch().then(function(r){
            retVal = r;
        });
        deferred.resolve(44);
        expect(retVal).toEqual(44);
    });

});
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
Chrome 36.0.1985 (Mac OS X 10.9.4) mocking services should be able to test values from both functions FAILED
        Expected undefined to equal 44.
        Error: Expected undefined to equal 44.
            at null.<anonymous> (/Users/selah/WebstormProjects/macrosim-angular/test/spec/services/usersAndRoles-service-test.js:34:24)
```

How can I make this test pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When mocking async calls with $q, you need to use `$rootScope.$apply()` because of how $q is implemented.

Specifically, the `.then` method does not get called synchronously, it is designed to always be async, regardless of how it was called - sync or async.

To achieve that, $q is integrated with $rootScope.  Therefore, in your unit tests, you need to notify the $rootScope that something was changed (ie - trigger a digest cycle).  To do that, you call `$rootScope.$apply()`

See [here (specifically the "Differences between Kris Kowal's Q and $q section")](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Working code looks like this:

```
describe('mocking services', function () {

    var someService, deferred, rootScope;

    beforeEach(function () {

        module(function($provide){
            $provide.factory('someService', function($q){
                return{
                    trySynch: function(){
                        return 33;
                    },
                    tryAsynch: function(){
                        deferred = $q.defer();
                        return deferred.promise;
                    }
                };
            });
        });

        inject(function ($injector) {
            someService = $injector.get('someService');
            rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
        });
    });

    it('should be able to test values from both functions', function () {
        expect(someService.trySynch()).toEqual(33);

        var retVal;
        someService.tryAsynch().then(function(r){
            retVal = r;
        });
        deferred.resolve(44);
        rootScope.$apply();
        expect(retVal).toEqual(44);
    });

});
```

Comment: I edited this to include the code as well as the description of why in one answer.  Thanks!

Comment: as a newbie unittester for angular code, I have to say thankyou. :p

Answer (score 0):

`$q`'s deferred is still resolving asynchronously.

Quick test, albeit in an older version of Angular: http://plnkr.co/edit/yg2COXG0TWBYniXOwJYb

This test should work:

```
it('should be able to test values from both functions', function (done) {

    expect(someService.trySynch()).toEqual(33);

    someService.tryAsynch().then(function(r){
        expect(r).toEqual(44);
        done();
    });

    deferred.resolve(44);
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.  The text passes when I make this change.  However the test still passes if I say expect(r).toEqual("junk") which leads me to believe that the asynchronous "expect" is not working still.

Comment: Strange. Seems more like the promise isn't actually resolving during the duration of the test to me... that'd explain why anything in the expect "works". Are you sure the test itself is asynchronous? I was under the impression Jasmine added the `done` method for async (v2.0 I believe) but that might not be in your version, in which case I'm less familiar with how to make it wait for the deferred resolve :)

Comment: At any rate I see that you've "fixed" it in your own answer, but if you'd like more help with a cleaner solve maybe you could post a plunkr showing the test failure.

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure how to get it set up on Plunkr unfortunately.  Thanks for your time though!

Answer (score 0):

If I run `rootScope.$apply()` before my expect clause that tests my asynchronous function then the test succeeds.  Also, it fails if I supply an incorrect value, as I would expect it to.

So my test is functional, but I don't however understand why rootScope.$apply() is important here, so if anyone wants to copy my code and provide an explanation I will gladly mark your answer as the correct answer!

My working test code looks like this:

```
describe('mocking services', function () {

    var someService, deferred, rootScope;

    beforeEach(function () {

        module(function($provide){
            $provide.factory('someService', function($q){
                return{
                    trySynch: function(){
                        return 33;
                    },
                    tryAsynch: function(){
                        deferred = $q.defer();
                        return deferred.promise;
                    }
                };
            });
        });

        inject(function ($injector) {
            someService = $injector.get('someService');
            rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
        });
    });

    it('should be able to test values from both functions', function () {
        expect(someService.trySynch()).toEqual(33);

        var retVal;
        someService.tryAsynch().then(function(r){
            retVal = r;
        });
        deferred.resolve(44);
        rootScope.$apply();
        expect(retVal).toEqual(44);
    });

});
```